# Why is cat /dev/random output changing?

Tags: linux, random, cat, tail

Using `cat /dev/random` on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) in Terminal yields unexpected results. If I'm not mistaken, `cat` should basically output the contents of the file and that's it, but in my case `cat` prints out random gibberish (as expected) and then continues to output more random gibberish every 5 seconds or so.

I've tried using`tail -f /dev/random` to see how the file changes but this surprisingly yields no output.

What is going on here?

Comment: @user01561848512: What's that supposed to mean...?

Comment: It's not a coding problem

Comment: So where should I post this question?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a (regular) file, first thing. It's a "character special file".

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/what-are-character-special-and-block-special-files-in-a-unix-system

Think of it as a "water fountain of random bytes".